# Freemarker: find specific object in array of arrays

Tags: html, jpa, spring-data-jpa, freemarker

I have a complex many-to-many relationship defined. The cross-reference table is an entity, so I have Contact with a One-To-Many to ContactList, and List with a One-To-Many to Contact List. Contact List contains listID, contactID, and a few Booleans. The relationships seem to work well and on the backend I can get a list of contacts on a review list using the Spring-Data-Jpa findByContactListsIn(Set).

However, I am trying to build a list of contacts in Freemarker, and show whether they were in the current list.

Before I made an Entity out of ContactList, I had a standard Many-To-Many relationship between them, and I was able to do something like this in my .ftl:

`<#if list.contacts?seq_contains(contact)>`

But I needed to add some data to ContactList specifically, so I needed it to be more complicated. How can I do something similar now? I tried:

`<#if list.contactLists?seq_contains(contact)`

But of course that always returns false, because it is comparing two different entity types. Is there a way to find if a contact is in one of the contactList objects?

I suppose I could do some back-end trickery, but I am looking for a front-end solution to this.

Comment: I'm starting to think I need to do this inside-out. I need to return a set of ContactList objects, instead of a List object. The backend will restrict it to a list of ContactLists with the listID, then I build my list of Contacts from that? Going to try this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `?seq_contains` for finding generic object at all. It doesn't call `Object.equals`, instead it works like the `==` operator of the template language, which only allows comparing strings, numbers, booleans and dates/times, otherwise it gives you an error. Unfortunately it won't fail in your case, because POJO-s are also strings (and their string value is what `toString()` returns). This is an unfortunate legacy of the stock `ObjectWrapper` (scheduled to be fixed in FM3); not even a quirk in the template language. Ideally you get an error there. Instead, now it silently compares the return value of the `toString()`-s...

Your data-model should already contain what the template should actually display. FTL is not a programming language, so if you try to extract that from the data-model in it, it will be a pain. But, that the data-model contains that data can also mean that some objects in the data-model have methods that extract the data you need. As a last resort, you can add objects that just contain helper methods.

Update: Returning to `?seq_contains`, if you need the Java semantics and `list` is a Java `Collection`, you can just use the Java API: `list?api.contains(contact)`.

Comment: I ended up getting it fixed last night, pretty much how you suggested. I sent a list of the contact IDs in the list, so when I show a list of contacts I check their I'd against that list. If they are there I add a remove button, if not I add an add button. 

But are you saying I have access to object methods in Freemarker? This is my first ftl project, and I did not know that! That's pretty huge.

Comment: For POJO-s yes; as per JavaBeans specification you can call the "actions" (public methods declared in a public class or interface). For `Map`-s and `List`-s you can't, unless you are using `?api` like (`myCustomMap?api.myMethod()`). Also for `String`-s, `Number`-s and `Date`-s you can't (they ain't POJO-s.) Actually, ultimately all depends on the `ObjectWrapper` in your FreeMarker `Configuration`, but the default one is like this.